# Removing openjdk-6-jre without the installation of sun-java6-jre

Tags: java, openjdk, jre

I have alrady installed (manually, from the .bin file) the latest jre (Version 6 Update 30) from oracle and now i want to remove the openjdk-6-jre. However, apt forces me to install old (Version 6 Update 26) sun-java6-jre! So, can I remove the openjdk-6-jre (and the icedtea plugin) without installing sun-java6-jre? Or is it trivial to try to remove openjdk-6-jre as it is "harmless"?

```
sudo apt-get remove openjdk-6-jre-headless
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  sun-java6-bin sun-java6-jre
Suggested packages:
  sun-java6-plugin ia32-sun-java6-plugin sun-java6-fonts ttf-kochi-gothic
  ttf-sazanami-gothic ttf-kochi-mincho ttf-sazanami-mincho ttf-arphic-uming
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  default-jre default-jre-headless icedtea-6-jre-cacao
  libcommons-beanutils-java libcommons-digester-java openjdk-6-jre
  openjdk-6-jre-headless openjdk-6-jre-lib
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  sun-java6-bin sun-java6-jre
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 8 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0B/35,1MB of archives.
After this operation, 12,3MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

Comment: Why not just agree to install it, and then remove it manually later?

Answer (score 2):

`sudo apt-get remove openjdk-6-jre-headless sun-java6-bin sun-java6-jre`

Of course that'll also remove all packages that depend on a JRE package. If you want to be able to use them, you'll need to create a dummy JRE package, with `equivs`.

So it's probably easier to just leave a packaged JRE installed.